# I am trying to boot android lollipop on raspberry pi2

Tags: pi-2, android

I have build AOSP for raspberry pi 2. i have created partitions on SD card as follows and put all required files at proper place.

Partitions-

boot : fat32 512 MB | system : ext4 512 MB | cache : ext4 512 MB | data : ext4 512 MB |

But while booting it gives me error.I have attach screen shot of error. please tell me how to solve this error.[image]

Comment: I would try to change storage card to something faster. Kingston has great cards Class 10 40MB/s up/down.

Comment: Did you yourself build AOSP for Raspberry Pi? Or did you simply copy files? If you have a link to a website, can you show it here?

Comment: yes i am building aosp for RPI2. AOSP download from : repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r4

Comment: yes i am building aosp for RPI2. AOSP download from : repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r4    and RPI2 device file link : https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi2

Comment: @FlashThunder That is a total wast of time since the pi's SD card reader won't exceed 25 MB/s no matter how many thousands of dollars you spend on a card.

Comment: @goldilocks you are wrong... changing card to better makes it much more responsive... it's not only about squential reading speed. Try it yourself. Especially in xwindows.

Comment: I am not wrong, the max speed of the card reader is 25 MB/s.  But fair enough, a better quality card is a better quality card.  That error certainly isn't due to a low quality card though, unless "low quality" means "broken" -- but I do not think it is the card at all, it is the kernel.  There's a reason you don't see a lot of people around here talking about android except, "I want to run android but it won't work".

Comment: It's not about max speed but random access... on $10 card its about 10 times slower than on $50 one. And most cards are FAR from 25 MB/s as well. You probably never tested it, I did, trust me. It does matter. And is visible especially on boot time and xwindows smoothness... the error says "timeout waiting for hardware interrupt" and it refers to memory card. So it has nothing to do with max read speed, but card not reporting to processor that it's ready (great simplification). PS. Noone answered that question, so worth a try. If it's not all about money.